# Oracle Bankers rule

Tags: oracle, numbers, rounding

Why Oracle is not using [Bankers rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) (the rounding method)?

Comment: I presume you really mean :-
Why does decimal arithmatic using the NUMBER data type in an ORAACLE database not use the half rounding scheme known as Bankers Rounding.

Comment: Because Oracle have more money than most bankers, and see no reason to take their advice?

Comment: taking a banker's advice ... sounds dangerous!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Accurate decimal arithmatic is a large and complex subject.

Google 'mike colishaw decimal rounding' if you want to read the ahem Oracle on the subject.

Basically there are many rounding schemes which are possible:-

Round everthing down - the default in most languages including C as Oracle is written in C this is probably why they do this.

Round everything up - rarely seen but occasionally needs to be implemented because of obscure market and tax rules.

Basic Half Rounding - anything above .5 rounds up everything else rounds down.

Generous Half Rounding - anything below .5 rounds down everthing else rounds up.

Bankers Rounding - Even numbers follow the Basic Half Rounding rule, odd numbers the Generous Half Rounding rule. This is rarely seen in actual banks which prefer rounding up if the moneys coming thier way and rounding down when its going the clients way.

ORACLE NUMBER is actually a pretty good Decimal Arithmatic implementation and is accurate as far as it goes.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has implemented *round half away from zero*:

```
SQL> select round(22.5) from dual
  2  /

ROUND(22.5)
-----------
         23

SQL> select round(23.5) from dual
  2  /

ROUND(23.5)
-----------
         24

SQL> select round(-23.5) from dual
  2  /

ROUND(-23.5)
------------
         -24

SQL> select round(-22.5) from dual
  2  /

ROUND(-22.5)
------------
         -23

SQL>
```

Why don't they change it to Bankers' Rounding?  Well, for most purposes *round half away from zero* is good enough.  Plus there's that old fallback, changing it would likely break too much of the existing codebase - Oracle's own as well as all their customers.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but someone may still need this. Oracle's binary floats and binary doubles follow the banker's rounding rule when rounding to a whole number. So you can use that. It's ugly but it works:

```
given : price = 2.445
SQL> select round(to_binary_float(price * 100)) / 100 as price_rounded from dual;

price_rounded
-------------
2.44

given : price = 2.435
SQL> select round(to_binary_float(price * 100)) / 100 as price_rounded from dual;

price_rounded
-------------
2.44
```

The multiply and divide by 100 are necessary in this example. I haven't been able to figure out the specifics of the behavior, but select round(to_binary_float(price), 2) for some decimal, price, does not seem to consistently round up or down by the same rules. I have found, however, that rounding to a whole number consistently gives me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can always implement your own function for banker's rounding as described [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1487672&page=1).

Answer (score 1):

Banker's rounding round's 0.5 to 0: it round's towards even numbers.

Comment: Oops, I put in the "explanation" of rounding 0.5 to 1. The OP did not mention it. Fixed now.