# number rounding to nearest even number with given precision in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

I am trying to round a number in oracle the same way as python does: to nearest even number (to a given precision):

```
python:
round(0.3125) -> 0.312

Oracle:
select round(0.3125, 3) from dual -> 0.313
```

Oracle can do this by specifying the input as float when rounding to integers:

```
select round(2.5f) from dual -> 2

select round(2.5)  from dual -> 3
```

But:

```
select round(0.3125f, 3) from dual -> 0.313 and not 0.312.
Any ideas?
```

Comment: Are you looking for `CEILING()`

Comment: Why do you need to round/truncate to the nearest even digit?  What happens if a number has no even digits?

Comment: @MT0 Your duplicate link does not look like it answers this question.  Hence, I will reopen.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The OP is assuming Python does "Round Half Even" (it doesn't as I note in my answer) but the solution to that rounding method is given in the question I marked it as a duplicate of.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, you always do really good Oracle work here.  This is behind my capability, unless I invested say 1-2 hours of research time :-(

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to round a number in oracle the same way as python does: to nearest even number (to a given precision):

Taken from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46973318/1509264) you can implement round half even as:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8279/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data( value ) AS
SELECT (LEVEL -11)/20 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 21
/

CREATE FUNCTION round_half_even(
  value NUMBER,
  prec  INTEGER DEFAULT 0
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  whole NUMBER := POWER( 10, -prec );
BEGIN
  RETURN CASE
         WHEN ABS( MOD( value, 2*whole ) ) = 0.5*whole
         THEN TRUNC( value, prec )
         ELSE ROUND( value, prec )
         END;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value,
       ROUND( value , 1),
       round_half_even( value, 1 )
FROM   test_data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8279/1/0)**:

```
| VALUE | ROUND(VALUE,1) | ROUND_HALF_EVEN(VALUE,1) |
|-------|----------------|--------------------------|
|  -0.5 |           -0.5 |                     -0.5 |
| -0.45 |           -0.5 |                     -0.4 |
|  -0.4 |           -0.4 |                     -0.4 |
| -0.35 |           -0.4 |                     -0.4 |
|  -0.3 |           -0.3 |                     -0.3 |
| -0.25 |           -0.3 |                     -0.2 |
|  -0.2 |           -0.2 |                     -0.2 |
| -0.15 |           -0.2 |                     -0.2 |
|  -0.1 |           -0.1 |                     -0.1 |
| -0.05 |           -0.1 |                        0 |
|     0 |              0 |                        0 |
|  0.05 |            0.1 |                        0 |
|   0.1 |            0.1 |                      0.1 |
|  0.15 |            0.2 |                      0.2 |
|   0.2 |            0.2 |                      0.2 |
|  0.25 |            0.3 |                      0.2 |
|   0.3 |            0.3 |                      0.3 |
|  0.35 |            0.4 |                      0.4 |
|   0.4 |            0.4 |                      0.4 |
|  0.45 |            0.5 |                      0.4 |
|   0.5 |            0.5 |                      0.5 |
```

**However**

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) states:

> The documentation for the built-in `round()` function says that it
>   rounds to the nearest value, rounding ties away from zero. Since the
>   decimal fraction 2.675 is exactly halfway between 2.67 and 2.68, you
>   might expect the result here to be (a binary approximation to) 2.68.
>   It’s not, because when the decimal string `2.675` is converted to a
>   binary floating-point number, it’s again replaced with a binary
>   approximation, whose exact value is
>
> ```
> 2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
> ```
>
> Since this approximation is slightly closer to 2.67 than to 2.68, it’s
>   rounded down.

So the way to implement python's `ROUND()` function in Oracle is to just use the built-in `ROUND()` function and know that python's implementation has slight rounding errors.

Comment: Thank you, I converted the function to plain sql, and it worked:
select
   CASE WHEN ABS(MOD( 0.3125, 2*(power( 10, -3)))) = 0.5 * (power (10, -3))   THEN TRUNC( 0.3125, 3 )
   ELSE ROUND( 0.3125, 3 )   END
from dual;

Answer (score 1):

Oracle supports [ROUND_TIES_TO_EVEN (number)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/ROUND_TIES_TO_EVEN-number.html#GUID-49919B6B-4337-4812-A248-B5D98F102DBD):

```
SELECT ROUND(0.3125, 3)              AS ROUND       -- 0.313
      ,ROUND_TIES_TO_EVEN(0.3125, 3) AS ROUND_EVEN  -- 0.312
FROM dual;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=102bb5d64b06971b58113f93820d1737)**

Answer (score 0):

### try this:

```
DECODE ( SIGN(MOD((0.3127*10000),10)- 5),1,round(0.3125,3),round( floor(0.3125*1000)/1000,3) )
```

Comment: This does not duplicate python's `ROUND` function.

Comment: It also doesn't round `0.3127` to `0.313`.